# It is possible to display a base64 gif?

Tags: swift, swift3

Hello I try to display a GIF that I get from a base64 file in a UIImageView but it only shows as an image does not play, I opted to use a WKWebView I managed to show it in emulators is displayed well but in iphone is not shown I appreciate your time and your opinion thanks. I share my code.

the image is displayed but does not move with an image view and with a WKWebView it is not displayed on a physical device but on emulators.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uFN6.png)

Comment: There’s no such thing as a “base64 gif”. There’s a gif, that can be base64 encoded, but it’s your job to decode it back into the original data.

Comment: I’ll add, you should avoid base64 encoding gifs. Their file sizes are already huge, and base64 encoding bloats that by a further 1.6x (only 5 bits of useful data per 8 bit byte of the encoded data)

Comment: It does not exist ?
So if the backend implements this functionality, your answer would be. 
It does not work or it is not well done !!! 
They must have their x or y reasons to send their base64 files, the frond simply receives the value, decodes it and displays it.

In case they exploded, I found a way to solve the problem.
I leave the code at the bottom.

Comment: No. You should simply comment, giving a link to the third-party library that you elected to use. Pasting the library code here is unnecessary, and pasting it without attribution is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

iOS has no native provision for playing an animated GIF. There are third-party libraries to help, but that would be outside the proper scope of Stack Overflow.